# Safari WebDriver Extension is not enabled with Jenkins user

Tags: java, macos, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, safari

When running a Selenium test suite from Jenkins towards the Safari browser, the needed SafariDriver Extension is listed as installed but not enabled. Hence a connection with the SafariDriver Extension cannot be established.

I've installed and enabled the extension manually and I'm also setting:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.safari.noinstall", "true");
```

Using: Selenium-java 2.48.2 and SafariDriver 2.48.0

Could this be a user related issue? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so it seems to be a bug in Selenium that is causing this issue. Unfortunately it has not been solved yet.

[Link to issue on code.google.com](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8391)

Following the link you can find a workaround which states that it will work if you run "another Jenkins instance" as master and have a slave agent on the OS X machine. Also one should fire up the slave agent with Java Web Start. I have not verified the workaround however.